# How to check SunJSSE provider for Java 17

Tags: java, java-17

Here is how I check SunJsse provider or not in Java 11.

```
    Class cls;
    try {
        cls = Class.forName("com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.Provider");
    } catch (ClassNotFoundException ex) {
        return null;
    }

    if(class !=null){
        System.out.println("SunJsse Provider");
    } else {
        System.out.println("Other provider");
    }

    Provider provider
    try {
        provider =  (Provider) cls.newInstance();
    } catch (IllegalAccessException ex) {
        throw new RuntimeException(ex);
    } catch (InstantiationException ex) {
        throw new RuntimeException(ex);
    }
```

But since **com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.Provider** been removed and classes not exist in Java 17 anymore. How to check the SunJSSE provider??

Answer (score 1):

Instead of directly checking the provider classes I would get the list of registered security providers and check it for the SunJSSE provider:

```
for (Provider p : Security.getProviders()) {
    if (p.getName().equals("SunJSSE")) {
        System.out.println("SunJSSE found in " + p.getClass());
    }
}
```

If I execute this in Java 17 I get `SunJSSE found in class sun.security.ssl.SunJSSE`